# db2 "DB21018E A system error occurred. The command line processor could not continue processing."

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I am using DB2 LUW v11.1 with BLU acceleration.

When I run the following code, I got the error "DB21018E  A system error occurred. The command line processor could not continue processing."

```
create table diabetes_v3_2.comm_outpatient_services_t2dm
    as (select * from commercial.outpatient_services)
    with no data
    not logged initially;
update command options using c off;
insert into diabetes_v3_2.comm_outpatient_services_t2dm
    select * from commercial.outpatient_services
        where enrolid in (
            select enrolid from diabetes_v3_2.t2dm_cohort_filter_age_enrollment
        );
commit;
```

The following is the error message:

```
/* Generate cohort data for the cohort after *  filtering according to age and continuous * enrollment criteria. */ /* facility header */ /* inpatient admissions */ /* inpatient services */ /* outpatient prescription drugs */ /* outpatient services */ create table diabetes_v3_2.comm_outpatient_services_t2dm as (select * from commercial.outpatient_services) with no data not logged initially
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

update command options using c off
DB20000I  The UPDATE COMMAND OPTIONS command completed successfully.

insert into diabetes_v3_2.comm_outpatient_services_t2dm select * from commercial.outpatient_services where enrolid in ( select enrolid from diabetes_v3_2.t2dm_cohort_filter_age_enrollment )
DB21018E  A system error occurred. The command line processor could not 
continue processing.
```

"commercial.outpatient_services" is a very large table (> 4 billion rows) and "diabetes_v3_2.t2dm_cohort_filter_age_enrollment" is smaller (~ 4 million rows).

**=== UPDATE 2017-02-09 11:48 EST===**

I check the db2 diagnostic log file: `/home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump/db2diag.log`. The following is the log I think related to the error:

```
2017-02-08-19.17.05.245747+000 E431913963E727        LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138686956037888 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
APPHDL  : 0-5261               APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.170208191704
AUTHID  : PANC                 HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 627                  EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, data management, sqldEndNoLogList, probe:1
MESSAGE : ADM5530W  The COMMIT processing of table
          "DIABETES_V3_2.COMM_OUTPATIENT_SERVICES_T2DM" that used NOT LOGGED
          INITIALLY has been initiated.  It is recommended that you take a
          backup of this table's table space(s).

2017-02-08-19.17.05.285806+000 E431914691E744        LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138686956037888 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
APPHDL  : 0-5261               APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.170208191704
AUTHID  : PANC                 HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 627                  EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, data management, sqldEndNoLogList, probe:1
MESSAGE : ADM5530W  The COMMIT processing of table "SYSIBM
          .SYN170208191705181821_COMM_OUTPATIENT_SERVICES_T2DM" that used NOT
          LOGGED INITIALLY has been initiated.  It is recommended that you take
          a backup of this table's table space(s).

.................
.................
.................
Skipped some logs
.................
.................
.................

2017-02-09-06.26.38.910171+000 E431936585E1146       LEVEL: Info
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138687035729664 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
APPHDL  : 0-6071               APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.170209054604
AUTHID  : DB2INST1             HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 575                  EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, relation data serv, sqlrr_rds_common_post, probe:5245
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8012006D=-2146303891=SQLR_CA_BUILT
          "SQLCA has already been built"
DATA #1 : String, 31 bytes
UCstate terminate bit is raised
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007E227FA2FD88 : 4301 0000                                  C...
DATA #3 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1224   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc:
 sqlerrp : SQLE05A
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate:
:
STOP    : Automatic reorg evaluation has finished successfully on database MYDATABASE

2017-02-09-06.26.38.910171+000 E431936585E1146       LEVEL: Info
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138687035729664 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
APPHDL  : 0-6071               APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.170209054604
AUTHID  : DB2INST1             HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 575                  EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, relation data serv, sqlrr_rds_common_post, probe:5245
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8012006D=-2146303891=SQLR_CA_BUILT
          "SQLCA has already been built"
DATA #1 : String, 31 bytes
UCstate terminate bit is raised
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007E227FA2FD88 : 4301 0000                                  C...
DATA #3 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1224   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc:
 sqlerrp : SQLE05A
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate:
:
STOP    : Automatic reorg evaluation has finished successfully on database MYDATABASE

2017-02-09-06.26.38.910171+000 E431936585E1146       LEVEL: Info
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138687035729664 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
APPHDL  : 0-6071               APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.170209054604
AUTHID  : DB2INST1             HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 575                  EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, relation data serv, sqlrr_rds_common_post, probe:5245
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8012006D=-2146303891=SQLR_CA_BUILT
          "SQLCA has already been built"
DATA #1 : String, 31 bytes
UCstate terminate bit is raised
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007E227FA2FD88 : 4301 0000                                  C...
DATA #3 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1224   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc:
 sqlerrp : SQLE05A
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate:
:
STOP    : Automatic reorg evaluation has finished successfully on database MYDATABASE

2017-02-09-06.26.38.910171+000 E431936585E1146       LEVEL: Info
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138687035729664 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
APPHDL  : 0-6071               APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.170209054604
AUTHID  : DB2INST1             HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 575                  EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, relation data serv, sqlrr_rds_common_post, probe:5245
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8012006D=-2146303891=SQLR_CA_BUILT
          "SQLCA has already been built"
DATA #1 : String, 31 bytes
UCstate terminate bit is raised
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007E227FA2FD88 : 4301 0000                                  C...
DATA #3 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1224   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc:
 sqlerrp : SQLE05A
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate:
:
STOP    : Automatic reorg evaluation has finished successfully on database MYDATABASE

2017-02-09-06.26.38.910171+000 E431936585E1146       LEVEL: Info
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138687035729664 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
APPHDL  : 0-6071               APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.170209054604
AUTHID  : DB2INST1             HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 575                  EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, relation data serv, sqlrr_rds_common_post, probe:5245
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8012006D=-2146303891=SQLR_CA_BUILT
          "SQLCA has already been built"
DATA #1 : String, 31 bytes
UCstate terminate bit is raised
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007E227FA2FD88 : 4301 0000                                  C...
DATA #3 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1224   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc:
 sqlerrp : SQLE05A
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate:
:
STOP    : Automatic reorg evaluation has finished successfully on database MYDATABASE

2017-02-09-06.26.38.910171+000 E431936585E1146       LEVEL: Info
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138687035729664 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
APPHDL  : 0-6071               APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.170209054604
AUTHID  : DB2INST1             HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 575                  EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, relation data serv, sqlrr_rds_common_post, probe:5245
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8012006D=-2146303891=SQLR_CA_BUILT
          "SQLCA has already been built"
DATA #1 : String, 31 bytes
UCstate terminate bit is raised
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007E227FA2FD88 : 4301 0000                                  C...
DATA #3 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1224   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc:
 sqlerrp : SQLE05A
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate:
:
STOP    : Automatic reorg evaluation has finished successfully on database MYDATABASE

2017-02-09-06.26.38.910171+000 E431936585E1146       LEVEL: Info
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138687035729664 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
APPHDL  : 0-6071               APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.170209054604
AUTHID  : DB2INST1             HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 575                  EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, relation data serv, sqlrr_rds_common_post, probe:5245
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8012006D=-2146303891=SQLR_CA_BUILT
          "SQLCA has already been built"
DATA #1 : String, 31 bytes
UCstate terminate bit is raised
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007E227FA2FD88 : 4301 0000                                  C...
DATA #3 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1224   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc:
 sqlerrp : SQLE05A
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate:
:
STOP    : Automatic reorg evaluation has finished successfully on database MYDATABASE

2017-02-09-06.26.38.910171+000 E431936585E1146       LEVEL: Info
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138687035729664 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
APPHDL  : 0-6071               APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.170209054604
AUTHID  : DB2INST1             HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 575                  EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, relation data serv, sqlrr_rds_common_post, probe:5245
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8012006D=-2146303891=SQLR_CA_BUILT
          "SQLCA has already been built"
DATA #1 : String, 31 bytes
UCstate terminate bit is raised
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007E227FA2FD88 : 4301 0000                                  C...
DATA #3 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1224   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc:
 sqlerrp : SQLE05A
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate:
:
STOP    : Automatic reorg evaluation has finished successfully on database MYDATABASE

2017-02-09-06.26.38.910171+000 E431936585E1146       LEVEL: Info
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138687035729664 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
APPHDL  : 0-6071               APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.170209054604
AUTHID  : DB2INST1             HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 575                  EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, relation data serv, sqlrr_rds_common_post, probe:5245
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8012006D=-2146303891=SQLR_CA_BUILT
          "SQLCA has already been built"
DATA #1 : String, 31 bytes
UCstate terminate bit is raised
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007E227FA2FD88 : 4301 0000                                  C...
DATA #3 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1224   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc:
 sqlerrp : SQLE05A
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate:
:
STOP    : Automatic reorg evaluation has finished successfully on database MYDATABASE

2017-02-09-06.26.38.910171+000 E431936585E1146       LEVEL: Info
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138687035729664 PROC : db2sysc 0
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138687035729664 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
APPHDL  : 0-6071               APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.170209054604
AUTHID  : DB2INST1             HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 575                  EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, relation data serv, sqlrr_rds_common_post, probe:5245
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8012006D=-2146303891=SQLR_CA_BUILT
          "SQLCA has already been built"
DATA #1 : String, 31 bytes
UCstate terminate bit is raised
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 4 bytes
0x00007E227FA2FD88 : 4301 0000                                  C...
DATA #3 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1224   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc:
 sqlerrp : SQLE05A
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate:

2017-02-09-06.26.38.915527+000 I431937732E706        LEVEL: Error
PID     : 2956                 TID : 140379364529920 PROC : db2acd 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, Health Monitor, db2AutoReorgExec, probe:190
DATA #1 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1224   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc:
 sqlerrp : db2Reorg
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x8037006D      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate: 55032

2017-02-09-06.26.38.915697+000 I431938439E404        LEVEL: Event
PID     : 2956                 TID : 140379364529920 PROC : db2acd 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, Health Monitor, db2AutoReorgExec, probe:10
STOP    : Automatic reorg has completed with errors on table MYDATABASE  ."DIABETES_V3_2"."COMM_OUTPATIENT_SERVICES_T2DM"

2017-02-09-06.26.39.385239+000 E431938844E612        LEVEL: Info
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138686956037888 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
APPHDL  : 0-5261               APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.170208191704
AUTHID  : PANC                 HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 627                  EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, buffer pool services, sqlbCleanupBeforeTerm, probe:8024
DATA #1 : SQLP_LSN8, PD_TYPE_SQLP_LSN8, 8 bytes
00000000D456386A
DATA #2 : SQLP_LSN8, PD_TYPE_SQLP_LSN8, 8 bytes
00000000D456386A

2017-02-09-06.26.39.514755+000 E431939457E992        LEVEL: Info
PID     : 2936                 TID : 139705853142784 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 591                  EDUNAME: db2loggr (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, data protection services, sqlpghck, probe:2820
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Log stream 0 has been marked consistent.
                 Head Extent ID: 0
           Group Head Extent ID: 0
                    Startup LSO: 0
                       Base LSO: 2864382783169
            Last Log Record LSO: 2864344546100
            Last Log Record LSN: 00000000D4563869
                       Next LSN: 00000000D456386A
                    Lowtran LSN: 00000000D456386A
                    Minbuff LSN: 00000000D456386A
                       Head LSN: 00000000D456386A
                 Group Head LSN: 00000000D456386A
              Group Minbuff LSN: 00000000D456386A

2017-02-09-06.26.39.521643+000 E431940450E480        LEVEL: Info
PID     : 2936                 TID : 139705853142784 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 591                  EDUNAME: db2loggr (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, data protection services, sqlpghck, probe:2889
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Database has been marked consistent.
                  Log File Size: 1000000

2017-02-09-06.26.42.281169+000 E431940931E549        LEVEL: Event
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, data protection services, sqlpghck, probe:2820
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Log stream 0 has been marked consistent.
                 Head Extent ID: 0
           Group Head Extent ID: 0
                    Startup LSO: 0
                       Base LSO: 2864382783169
            Last Log Record LSO: 2864344546100
            Last Log Record LSN: 00000000D4563869
                       Next LSN: 00000000D456386A
                    Lowtran LSN: 00000000D456386A
                    Minbuff LSN: 00000000D456386A
                       Head LSN: 00000000D456386A
                 Group Head LSN: 00000000D456386A
              Group Minbuff LSN: 00000000D456386A

2017-02-09-06.26.39.521643+000 E431940450E480        LEVEL: Info
PID     : 2936                 TID : 139705853142784 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 591                  EDUNAME: db2loggr (MYDATABASE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, data protection services, sqlpghck, probe:2889
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Database has been marked consistent.
                  Log File Size: 1000000

2017-02-09-06.26.42.281169+000 E431940931E549        LEVEL: Event
PID     : 2936                 TID : 138686956037888 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : MYDATABASE
APPHDL  : 0-5261               APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.170208191704
AUTHID  : PANC                 HOSTNAME: remote.server.host.name
EDUID   : 627                  EDUNAME: db2agent (idle) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqeLocalDatabase::FreeResourcesOnDBShutdown, probe:15912
STOP    : DATABASE: MYDATABASE   : DEACTIVATED: NO
```

I noticed the error code `sqlcode: -1224` in the log, then I checked the meaning of this code by using `db2 ? sql1224` which says:

```
SQL1224N  The database manager is not able to accept new requests, has
      terminated all requests in progress, or has terminated the
      specified request because of an error or a forced interrupt.
```

But there could be many possibilities that the database manager does not accept new requests. How to further investigate?

**=== UPDATE 2017-02-09 20:51 ===**

Instead of using `INSERT`, I used `LOAD` to populate the table. The following is the script:

```
create table diabetes_v3_2.comm_outpatient_services_t2dm
    as (select * from commercial.outpatient_services)
    with no data;

declare load_cursor cursor for
    select * from commercial.outpatient_services
        where enrolid in (
            select enrolid from diabetes_v3_2.t2dm_cohort_filter_age_enrollment
        );

load from load_cursor of cursor insert into diabetes_v3_2.comm_outpatient_services_t2dm;
```

However, I still got an error (a different one):

```
/* Generate cohort data for the cohort after *  filtering according to age and continuous * enrollment criteria. */ /* facility header */ /* inpatient admissions */ /* inpatient services */ /* outpatient prescription drugs */ /* outpatient services */ create table diabetes_v3_2.comm_outpatient_services_t2dm as (select * from commercial.outpatient_services) with no data
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

declare load_cursor cursor for select * from commercial.outpatient_services where enrolid in ( select enrolid from diabetes_v3_2.t2dm_cohort_filter_age_enrollment )
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

load from load_cursor of cursor insert into diabetes_v3_2.comm_outpatient_services_t2dm
SQL3501W  The table space(s) in which the table resides will not be placed in
backup pending state since forward recovery is disabled for the database.

SQL1193I  The utility is beginning to load data from the SQL statement "
select * from commercial.outpatient_services where enrolid in ( s...".

SQL3500W  The utility is beginning the "ANALYZE" phase at time "02/09/2017
19:22:52.072421".

SQL3519W  Begin Load Consistency Point. Input record count = "0".

SQL3520W  Load Consistency Point was successful.

SQL3515W  The utility has finished the "ANALYZE" phase at time "02/09/2017
20:34:46.664280".

SQL3500W  The utility is beginning the "LOAD" phase at time "02/09/2017
20:34:46.665758".

SQL0952N  Processing was cancelled due to an interrupt.  SQLSTATE=57014

SQL3185W  The previous error occurred while processing data from row
"210184038" of the input file.

SQL0952N  Processing was cancelled due to an interrupt.  SQLSTATE=57014

SQL0952N  Processing was cancelled due to an interrupt.  SQLSTATE=57014

DB21018E  A system error occurred. The command line processor could not
continue processing.
```

This links to the related entries I found in db2diag.log: https://github.com/panCtrlV/storage/blob/master/db2_load_from_cursor_error_log-hide

Comment: Check for an entry in db2diag.log

Comment: @data_henrik I added some related logs from `db2diag.log`.

Comment: `DB21018E` is a client-side error, it's unlikely it will produces anything in the diagnostic log. @PanChao -- any particular reason you don't want to use `LOAD`? `INSERT`ing 4 million rows is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for the suggestions. It seems that using `LOAD` can also avoid logging, which caused me headache (but fixed). If I use `LOAD`. Do I have to first export the result of the `select ...` to a local file and then load the data into the table from the local file?

Comment: @mustaccio I found that maybe I can use "load from cursor" functionality of db2.

Comment: Here's the [manual link about loading from a cursor](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/c0005437.html) to get you started.

Comment: @mustaccio Still got errors. See update.

Comment: I suggest you speak with your DBA or, if you have no DBA, to IBM support. I'll vote to close this because it's off-topic here and too broad/off-topic at dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by my group's db expert, I used old fashioned way to create the table, then used "load from cursor" (suggested by @mustaccio) to populate the table from `select ...`.

The following is how the new script looks like and it succeeded this time:

```
create table diabetes_v3_2.comm_outpatient_services_t2dm (
    col1_name col1_type,
    col2_name col1_type,
    ...
);

declare load_cursor cursor for
    select * from commercial.outpatient_services
        where enrolid in (
            select enrolid from diabetes_v3_2.t2dm_cohort_filter_age_enrollment
        );

load from load_cursor of cursor insert into diabetes_v3_2.comm_outpatient_services_t2dm;
```